# Define default implementation of template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, default

I know it is possible to define default values for template parameters:

```
template<int N = 10> struct Foo {};
```

You can use this like `Foo<>` for example, but I want to be able to write just `Foo`.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work (throws compiler exception):

```
struct Foo : Foo<10> {};
```

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: `Foo` is not a type. `Foo` is a template. So no, you need the angle brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly, but can achieve something close thanks to a `typedef`, i.e.

```
template<int N = 10> struct Foo{};

typedef Foo<> DefaultFoo;//Or whatever name that fits, just not 'Foo'

int main() {
    DefaultFoo myFoo;
    return 0;
}
```